# jquery.load() to POST all elements of a form rather than having to specify what to POST

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an existing HTML form that I'm trying to update to use jQuery.load(). How can I pass all of the elements of the form as POST parameters rather than having to specify which parameters to pass?

The form elements are created dynamically by a script and the number of elements as well as the name of the elements varies considerably to the extent that it's not practical to specify which parameters to pass via AJAX/POST. Is there a simple way to pass to jQuery.load() all of the elements within the `<form></form>` tags as if the form was submitted traditionally?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `.serialize()` to serialize all of the inputs of the form for submitting along with your jQuery.load() call.

```
$('form').serialize()
```

For example, using `jQuery.load()` (only does GET unless you pass it an object for data, then POST)

```
$.load(
    'postTo.php', 
    $('#yourFormId').serialize(), 
    complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        //do your processing after the fact
}))
```

Using, `jQuery.ajax()`, you can make it POST

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'postTo.php',
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': $('#yourFormId').serialize(),
    'success': function(result){
         //process here
    }
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: How can I apply this in a way that would duplicate the normal functionality of submitting a form using POST? I'm trying to get the results in the same format ($_POST) array, which contains nested arrays.

Comment: Ah, you won't be able to `POST` with `load()` as it uses `GET`. You'll want to use `$.ajax` or something else to actually change the method to `POST`. I'll update my original post to show this.

Comment: Have you considered using $.post() ?

Comment: Actually, scratch that, you should be able to do POST through `$.load` after reading it, you'll have to use something other than `.serialize` though. Let me look into it.

Comment: You'd have to write your own function to spit the form out as JSON if you're going to want to use `$.load`, I'm going to update my post to show how to do it using `$.ajax`

Comment: @Splash-X haha, that'd work too :). Sometimes I think there are too many functions in jQuery that do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.. the above .ajax() example worked perfectly for me. Could not get the .load() to work for whatever reason. Were they supposed to be identical?

Comment: Nope, `$.load()` by default sends a `GET` request unless you pass it an object as the `data`. What `$.serialize()` creates is a URL-encoded notation of the form (like a querystring) so like `key1=value1&key2=value2`, which is not an object so `$.load()` will send a `GET`. `$.ajax()` is the method that method that any AJAX jQuery methods use, so it's more robust than `$.load()` as you can change any of the settings to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 32):

**Easy**: When you gather your form data and past it as the second parameter to `load()`, use `serializeArray(data)`, and don't use `serialize(data)`, as the currently accepted answer recommends.

`serialize()` returns a string, whereas `serializeArray()` returns an object.
`load()` sends a POST if the data is an object. If data is a string, `load()` sends a GET.

Comment: both the answers helped a lot. Using $.load was able to change the given div, using ajax call very easily, but couldn't find the same way to do it in $.ajax.